# $\trianglelefteq$ vs $\triangleleft$ for normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

What is the difference between using $\trianglelefteq$ and $\triangleleft$ to denote a normal subgroup? I've seen both used but haven't been able to find if there is a difference.

Comment: In my experience they are analogous to $\le$ and $<$: $H\trianglelefteq G$ allows $H$ to be equal to $G$, while $H\triangleleft G$ requires $H$ to be a proper normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: You have to be careful, because different authors use different conventions. It is similar to $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ for set containment.

Comment: Because of the ambiguity mentioned by Derek, it's often nice to avoid $\subset$, and instead use $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$. The only problem is that for normal subgroups, there is no analogue of the $\subsetneq$ in LaTeX /amssymbols (maybe this has been updated recently though?). You can do it manually in a LaTeX file (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33797/13669)), but I couldn't get this hack to work here.

Comment: [That is, authors use $\lhd$ to mean either "normal" or "proper normal". However, getting around this ambiguity genuinely hurts, so it would be nice if people used $\lhd$ just for proper normal.]

Answer (score 4):

In some references (for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20a%20normal,G%20and%20n%20%E2%88%88%20N.)), the author uses $H \triangleleft G$ to denote that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. In this case, $H$ is a subset of $G$ (which can be equal to $G$).

There are also some references which prefer to make the distinction between normal subgroups and proper normal subgroups. So they will use $H\trianglelefteq G$ to denote that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H\triangleleft G$ to denote that $H$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$ (which means that $H$ cannot be equal to $G$).